# Let m be any positive integer and let k be an even integer. Show that there exist a, b ∈ Z with k = a − b and gcd(a, m) = gcd(b, m) = 1.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let m be any positive integer and let k be an even integer. Show that there exist a, b ∈ Z with k = a − b and gcd(a, m) = gcd(b, m) = 1.

This problem seems simple but is quite difficult to approach. I tried the Chinese remainder theorem but failed. I want to ask for a proof for this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the prime factorization of $m$ are $ \prod_{i=1}^u P_i^{m_{P_i}} \prod_{j=1}^v Q_j^{m_{Q_j}}$ and prime factorization of $k$ are $\prod_{i=1}^u P_i^{k_{P_i}} \prod_{j=1}^w R_j^{k_{R_j}}$. For each $j$, there exists $S_j$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^u P_i^{k_{P_i}} +S_j \not\equiv 0 (\bmod Q_j)$ and $S_j \not\equiv 0 (\bmod Q_j)$, since $Q_j \neq 2$. By Chinese remainder theorem, there exists $S \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^u P_i^{k_{P_i}} +S \not\equiv 0 (\bmod Q_j)$ and $S \not\equiv 0 (\bmod Q_j)$. We can also assume $S$ relatively prime to all $P_i$, else we can replace $S$ by $S+ \prod Q_j$. Finally, we can pick $b=\prod_{j=1}^w R_j^{k_{R_j}}S$. Now, it is clear from the construction that $\gcd(b,m)$=1. It is also not hard to show that for $a=k+b$, we have $\gcd(a,m)=1$.

PS: Case $\prod_{j=1}^v Q_j^{m_{Q_j}}=1$ you can pick $b=1$.

Comment: Thanks! Nice solution!